# In python how do I get the value of kern.module_path?

Tags: python, kernel, freebsd

In python how can I get the value of the sysctl kern.module_path?

I know I can use popen to open sysctl(1) as a subprocess. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does reading `/proc/sys/kern/module_path` work? I don’t know how it is on BSD.

Comment: @roippi that library cool; post an answer and I'll +1 it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is the sysctl library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sysctl/0.1b2

Alternatively, you could use ctypes to interface directly with the C library. There's already a stackoverflow answer with an example of how to read sysctl values here: [python ctypes and sysctl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759892/python-ctypes-and-sysctl)

(Obviously, if you wanted to set values, you would have to modify that ctypes example a little).