# Python standard library to get total memory size

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is a module in python standard library I can use to get the total physical memory size. I know I can use psutil, but it would be great if my python script can run without installing external module. Thanks!

Edited:
Sorry guys, I forgot to mention that I'm using a mac OSX. Thanks for all the windows solutions tho!

Comment: On Linux, you can parse `/proc/meminfo` using regular file operations.

Comment: ya...unfortunately I'm using a mac :X

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/22102999/427158

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, you can use [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx), which requires only ctypes and no additional modules.

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_int32, c_uint64, sizeof, byref, windll
class MemoryStatusEx(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('length', c_int32),
        ('memoryLoad', c_int32),
        ('totalPhys', c_uint64),
        ('availPhys', c_uint64),
        ('totalPageFile', c_uint64),
        ('availPageFile', c_uint64),
        ('totalVirtual', c_uint64),
        ('availVirtual', c_uint64),
        ('availExtendedVirtual', c_uint64)]
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = sizeof(self)
```

Used like this:

```
>>> m = MemoryStatusEx()
>>> assert windll.kernel32.GlobalMemoryStatusEx(byref(m))
>>> print('You have %0.2f GiB of RAM installed' % (m.totalPhys / (1024.)**3))
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911863/1530134), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/760276/1530134), and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems) for information for MAC OS X/other UNIX systems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm using a mac...

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems)?

Answer (score 1):

I've utilized this function in a Windows environment previously.

```
import os
process = os.popen('wmic memorychip get capacity')
result = process.read()
process.close()
totalMem = 0
for m in result.split("  \r\n")[1:-1]:
    totalMem += int(m)

print totalMem / (1024**3)
```

---

This utilizes [`wmic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb742610.aspx) and the following command `wmic memorychip get capacity`, which you can run from your command line to see output in bytes.

This command reads the capacity of each memory module in the machine (in bytes) and then converts the total to gigabytes.

---

Example:

```
> wmic memorychip get capacity
Capacity
4294967296
4294967296
```

This shows I have two 4 GB chips.

```
> python get_totalmemory.py
8
```

Adding those two module capacities and doing a quick conversion shows I have 8 GB of RAM on this machine.

Comment: That seems a bit excessive for something that's exposed by the kernel API...

Comment: This works for me, although I had to change the `split` pattern to `"  \n\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [discussion](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-205082.html) there seems to nothing in Python's standard library that'll do that. Here's a few that might help:

- [Python System
  Information](https://bitbucket.org/chrismiles/psi/wiki/Home)
- [Psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) (Up-to-date, good cross
  platform support, I've used this before, not in Blender though)
- [SIGAR](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) (looks fairly 
  recent, supports a number of platforms)

Comment: Ya I saw that discussion when I googled it. I didn't count on it because it was 5 yrs ago, so I decided to post it here again. Psutil definitely works, it's just I don't want the users to have to install external libs when using my script.